# Gwt, how to make AbsolutePanel with transparent background in UiBinder?

Tags: gwt, uibinder

Lt see this code in UiBinder file

```
<g:AbsolutePanel>
   <g:at left='10' top='20'>
      <g:Label>Lorem ipsum...</g:Label>
   </g:at>
   <g:Label>...dolores est.</g:Label>
</g:AbsolutePanel>
```

Gwt, how to make the above AbsolutePanel to have transparent background?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using css.

```
.transparent
{
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: 0.9;
}
```

Change the opacity level according to your preference. Then add this class to your absolute panel